# custom app.config in c# generates configuration system failed to initialize exception

Tags: c#, winforms, paypal, app-config

**I checked all the solutions on internet related to  configuration    system failed to initialize exception but none of them working for    me.
       So I am posting this question.**

I am working on `PayPal REST API` in winform c#. I customized my `app.config` file. When I rebuild the application It shows the `Configuration system failed to initialize`

Here is **Default** app.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And  Here is my **Custom** app.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

<!--PayPal SDK settings-->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="__CLIENT_ID__" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="__CLIENT_SECRET__" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>

</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

I used try catch block to catch the exception, otherwise program does not terminate but working abnormally. My call stack is empty. I used try catch on form load.

Comment: What about a stack trace? Does the inner exception provide more information?

Comment: basically I used try catch block to catch the exception, otherwise program does not terminate but working abnormally.
My call stack is empty.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco I used try catch on form load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Problem Solved by putting the `<configSection>` as the first child element of `<configuration>`.

It was a rearrange of code.

Here is the new code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
 </configSections>
 <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>

 <!--PayPal SDK settings-->
 <paypal>
   <settings>
     <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
     <add name="clientId" value="__CLIENT_ID__" />
     <add name="clientSecret" value="__CLIENT_SECRET__" />
   </settings>
 </paypal>

</configuration>
```